# i want to get review on my logo which i have created for noor ul quran

Tags: logo

so this logo is for learning quran and other religion teachings does this communicate according to things i mentioned ? give me some review on it

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You should have no problem here. If it's in accordance with Quran, it's not at all needed. If it clashes with the Quran it should be deleted and the painter has earned a punishment.